Error while creating migrations with dotnet-ef in Web API project
The problem is that we encounter this error when creating a new migrations using the following commands.
dotnet ef migrations add "Add Identity Schema" 
    --project ../src/api/migrations/MSSQL/ 
    --context IdentityDbContext -o Identity

I get this error:

Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type 'TodoDbContext'. The exception 'Unable to resolve service for type 'Finbuckle.MultiTenant.Abstractions.IMultiTenantContextAccessor`1[App.Framework.Infrastructure.Tenant.appTenantInfo]' while attempting to activate 'App.WebApi.Todo.Persistence.TodoDbContext'.' was thrown while attempting to create an instance. For the different patterns supported at design time


Based on the error message, you're using this lib, right? Did you configure it based on the doc? There you'll find the lines you should add to register all the services needed. For example:
builder.Services.AddMultiTenant<TenantInfo>()
.WithHostStrategy()
.WithConfigurationStore();

app.UseMultiTenant();

